# Doctrine querybuilder with MEMBER OF and empty parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The Query below works only if I select something in parameter tag otherwise it return an empty result. How can I do to have it works like if there is no where restriction when parameter tag is empty. In the case below f.tags is a relation field many to many between entity Student and entity Tags.

```
public function FindStudent($tags)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('s');

    if ($tags) {
        $qb->andWhere(':tag MEMBER OF s.tags')
            ->setParameter('tag', $tags);
    }

    $qb->Select('s');

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

In profiler Doctrine query has an empty IN when nothing is selected. What I am trying to do is to have no INNER JOIN and WHERE IN at all when parameter tag is empty.

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student_tag f3_ INNER JOIN tag s4_ ON f3_.tag_id = s4_.id WHERE f3_.student_id = f0_.id AND s4_.id IN ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably

```
if(!empty($tags)){
```

Will do the trick.

Edit from your comment:
In that case:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
....
if(!empty($tags) && ($tags instanceof ArrayCollection && !$tags->empty())){
```

Comment: I tried this but I have same behavior. I don't know why since dump on `if(!empty($tags))` give 'true' in the profiler.

Comment: What is the value of $tags?

Comment: Dump on $tags return this in profiler: `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1565 ▼
  -elements: []
}` and it return this if I select some tags: `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1663 ▼
  -elements: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Entity\Saptag {#1635 ▶}
    1 => App\Entity\Saptag {#1648 ▶}
    2 => App\Entity\Saptag {#1627 ▶}
  ]
}` it sounds like if querybuilder don't not read if condition when creating the query

Comment: Thank you, it works I just change a detail in method empty of ArrayCollection: `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
....
if(!empty($tags) && ($tags instanceof ArrayCollection && !$tags->isEmpty())){`